# Does the electric fuel pump get damaged?

Tags: electrical, fuel-system, fuel-pump

The lorry was working just fine, and suddenly it stopped on its own. We did the checks including wiring, and finally, we discovered that it was a blown fuse which was no longer supplying power to the power.
The other guy came, he wanted to test the fuel pump. He connected a long cable from the battery directly to the fuel pump. Then the owner of the car, later on, called me telling me that the lorry is losing power, its power has now decreased.

My question is, does the electric fuel pump gets damaged (just like the starter motor armature?)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure I understand the question, but for the most part, the fuel pump is like any other mechanical thing: it will wear out over time. If you are wondering if by applying power directly to the fuel pump, then no, that in and of itself should not have done any damage to the fuel pump.

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the reply. We did the troubleshooting again and found out that it was a sensor which caused the problem, but I'm not sure which sensor is that that causes power loss on vehicles.